# How to filter multiple data on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing like this and it is working

```
$scope.data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, {dataType: term ,status : 'F'});
```

But i have to filter data with two status

```
 $scope.data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, {dataType: term ,status : 'F' ,status:'E'});
```

But it is taking either of one status only . ( either F or E )

Please suggest .

I want to filter based on term and status F and E

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you have written is wrong. You are basically passing an object with duplicate keys. In strict mode, that will not work. In non-strict mode, it will take the last value, which is E in your case.

Now, coming to the solution...
I take it that you want to filter data with status F or E. 
You can write a custom filter to filter your data in anyway you want... something like the below.

```
angular.module('yourAppName').filter('myFilter', function() {
 return function(input, criteria) {
       // your filter logic
 };
});
```

and you may invoke your filter by passing an array of values you want to filter.

```
$scope.data = $filter('myFilter')($scope.data, {status : ["A", "B"]});
```

How you implement is totally up to you (probably you will use underscore), but you get the general idea... To learn more about filters, have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)